# Obtaining pairs of coresponding items from two lists in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, iteration, java-stream

So my problem is really simple. Having two lists, lets say: `listA = {1,2,3,4}` and `listB = {5,6,7,8}` I want to do some operations on pairs of items from different lists on coresponding positions so I want basically `(1,5), (2,6), (3,7), (4,8)`. I know how to do it with external iterator but was wondering is there any nice solution of this problem using Stream Java 8 API. Second question is is there any way to skip creating `Pair<T>` class?

Comment: What you are trying to do is called "zipping" in functional programming. See the linked question.

Comment: Sorry for duplication. So is there any way to do something like `someList.stream().???????.foreach((x,y) -> ... )` ? Like changing the arity of stream, so in each element of stream i would have a pair which could be used as above?

Comment: Not with the Stream API itself. You either have to use an `IntStream` over the indices of the list or you can use StreamEx library which provdes a zip facility.